# Fluent API, define a primary key as foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have this two models :

```
//Primary AND Foreign key 1
public int UserID {get; set;}

//Primary AND Foreign key 2
public int ProductID {get; set;}
```

I don't know how to set this two column as primary keys and foreign keys in the same time !
Can you help me ?

Comment: foreign key to which table/entity?

Comment: Is this a many-to-many relationship? See this blog post, it may help you: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/17/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-6-many-valued-associations.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for this

```
    //Primary AND Foreign key 1
[Key]
 public int UserID {get; set;}
[ForeignKey("UserID")]
public virtual IEnumerable<UserProfile> users;

    //Primary AND Foreign key 2

public int ProductID {get; set;}
[ForeignKey("ProductID")]
public virtual IEnumerable<Product> products;
```

This will allow you navigate from user to products.

If this is not what you are looking for, please provide some more details on what you need